# Doesn't keep previously selected value in select box when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down within my webpage (code below):

```
<select id="SelectedNumber" >
<option label="choose one"></option>
<option value ="1.aspx">1</option>
<option value ="2.aspx">2</option>
<option value ="3.aspx">3</option>
<option value ="4.aspx">4</option> 
</select>
```

This calls this function when the value is changed and reloads a new URL (code below:)

```
 $(function(){

          // bind change event to select
          $('#SelectNumber').bind('change', function () {
              var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value

              if (url) { // require a URL
                  window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + url; // redirect

              }
              return false;
          });
        });
```

Now my problem is when the page is reloaded I want it to remember the option which was selected, not the option which is first in the dropdown. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use a cookie or local storage. There are many examples here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// load last selected URL from local storage
var selectedURL = localStorage.selectedURL;

// add a "selected" attribute to the element if there is a saved state
if(selectedURL)
    $("#SelectedNumber option[value='" + selectedURL + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

// bind change event to select
$('#SelectedNumber').bind('change', function () {
    var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value

    if (url) { // require a URL
        // save selected url to local storage
        localStorage.selectedURL = url;

        window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + url; // redirect
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work.. put it in a j fiddle would be easier for me to see it

Comment: @PeteTong Did you remember to do it after the DOM is ready? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yduLe

Answer (score 0):

try jquery cookie plugin like this:

```
$( document ).ready(init) ;

function init() {
  // restore value if present 
  var cookieValue = $.cookie("comboValue");
  if (cookieValue) {
    $('#SelectedNumber').val(cookieValue);
  }

  // bind change event to select
  $('#SelectedNumber').bind('change', function () {
      var index = $(this).val(); // get selected value

      // Store the combo index value into a cookie
      $.cookie("comboValue", index);

      if (url) { 
          // window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + url; // redirect

          // forcing reload in order to simulate navigation to another page.
          location.reload();

      }
      return false;
  });  
}
```

Also noticed some 'id' mismatches like SelectNumber and SelectNumber, you have to correct in your code.